# Jazz Rest Service: Retrieve the folder name of a change set?

Tags: java, rest, jazz

I retrieved the following changeset:

```
{
  "changes": [
    {
      "kind": 10,
      "item": {
        "uri": "itemOid\/com.ibm.team.filesystem.FileItem\/_2ItWACJKEeGAaaEbbqTtgw",
        "itemId": "_2ItWACJKEeGAaaEbbqTtgw",
        "com.ibm.team.repository.typeName": "com.ibm.team.filesystem.FileItem"
      },
      "before": "_Ngn9BCJeEeG25dOp_iUerQ",
      "after": "_WLdK4iJ5EeG63tfBsj11_Q",
      "internalId": "_WL7E8CJ5EeG63tfBsj11_Q"
    },
    {
      "kind": 1,
      "item": {
        "uri": "itemOid\/com.ibm.team.scm.Folder\/_Uy41cCJ5EeGmx9rBZ7tE2Q",
        "itemId": "_Uy41cCJ5EeGmx9rBZ7tE2Q",
        "com.ibm.team.repository.typeName": "com.ibm.team.scm.Folder"
      },
      "before": null,
      "after": "_WLdK5SJ5EeG63tfBsj11_Q",
      "internalId": "_WL7E8SJ5EeG63tfBsj11_Q"
    }
  ],
  "comment": "",
  "lastUpdatedDate": "2011-12-09T15:21:04.795Z",
  "active": false,
  "owner": {
    "uri": "itemOid\/com.ibm.team.repository.Contributor\/_hhbosPC1EeCsJbI2ZgPDog",
    "itemId": "_hhbosPC1EeCsJbI2ZgPDog",
    "com.ibm.team.repository.typeName": "com.ibm.team.repository.Contributor"
  },
  "com.ibm.team.repository.typeName": "com.ibm.team.scm.ChangeSet",
  "stateId": "_aSiVASJ5EeG63tfBsj11_Q",
  "component": {
    "uri": "itemOid\/com.ibm.team.scm.Component\/_auolkPC9EeCek69P-ztT9w",
    "itemId": "_auolkPC9EeCek69P-ztT9w",
    "com.ibm.team.repository.typeName": "com.ibm.team.scm.Component"
  },
  "contextId": "_Dp6kMdwTEd2jUupDpQV1Rw",
  "predecessor": "_WL7sACJ5EeG63tfBsj11_Q",
  "modified": "2011-12-09T15:21:04.852Z",
  "mergePredecessor": null,
  "uri": "itemOid\/com.ibm.team.scm.ChangeSet\/_WKycgSJ5EeG63tfBsj11_Q",
  "itemId": "_WKycgSJ5EeG63tfBsj11_Q",
  "properties": [

  ],
  "modifiedBy": {
    "uri": "itemOid\/com.ibm.team.repository.Contributor\/_hhbosPC1EeCsJbI2ZgPDog",
    "itemId": "_hhbosPC1EeCsJbI2ZgPDog",
    "com.ibm.team.repository.typeName": "com.ibm.team.repository.Contributor"
  },
  "xComponentLink": null,
  "etag": "_aSiVASJ5EeG63tfBsj11_Q"
}
```

Now I want to find the name of the folder that was changed. How can I do that? I'm using the REST API.